# how to Manually shuffle the array list

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist contains some values that are in an order (correct positions), Now I want to swipe/set/manual shuffle change the values into disorder of the arraylist.  Below image can give my idea.Change Array-II to Array-I. To shuffle we can use collection.shuffle(), but here I have a text file, in that text file i wrote a original position as well as current position of the data in the array on to the text file. for example imaging, we have a text file name MyFile.txt, I wrote data in that like this, "original_position~Current_position" for example 
0~0
1~2
2~4
3~3
4~1
so, based on the above data i would to shuffle/ set the array.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I found Solution to my question please observer here.
"itemList_dump" is an arraylist which contains data.

```
if (i < itemList_dump.size()) {

    MyBitamp Data = itemList_dump.get(original_position_val);
            // setting Values according to our algorithm
                    Data.setItemCurPos(original_position_val);
                    Data.setItemPosition(current_positon_val);
                    Data.setrotation(rotataion_val);

                }
            }
            Collections.sort(itemList_dump, new Comparator<MyBitamp>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(MyBitamp o1, MyBitamp o2) {
                    if (o1.getItemPosition() > o2.getItemPosition()) {
                        return 1;
                    } else if (o1.getItemPosition() < o2.getItemPosition()) {
                        return -1;
                    } else {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `Collections.shuffle(YOUR_ARRAY_LIST);` to do it.

```
    List<String> ranList = new ArrayList<String>();
    // populate the list
    ranList.add("A");
    ranList.add("B");
    ranList.add("C");
    System.out.println("Initial collection: " + ranList);
    // shuffle the list
    Collections.shuffle(ranList);
    System.out.println("Final collection after shuffle: " + ranList);
```

The way of approach for manual sorting goes like this:

Read and add your data from file to `Map`

```
    private static Map<String, String> readFile(String fileNameWithPath) throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    File file = new File(fileNameWithPath);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String sCurrentLine;
    String[] splitPosition;
    while ((sCurrentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        splitPosition = sCurrentLine.split("~");
        map.put(splitPosition[0], splitPosition[1]);
    }
    return map;
}
```

And your main method is like:

```
   try {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> customeRandomList = new LinkedList<String>();
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("C");
        list.add("D");
        list.add("E");
        Map<String, String> map = Test.readFile("D://RandomList.txt");
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            customeRandomList.add(list.get(Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue())));
        }
        for (String result : customeRandomList) {
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: That could be simple, i know that, but here senario is different, I have data in the text file, That text file contains, original_position as well as current_position of the array, based on that i would like to set the data in array-II. i.e manual shuffle.

Comment: Is your manual shuffle will be always same. As such the 0,1,2,3,4 should be always be shuffle to 0,2,4,3,1

Comment: Could you please expose that sample file.

Comment: I found solution for that: here !if (i < itemList_dump.size()) {
      
      
      
      MyBitamp Data = itemList_dump.get(original_position_val);

      // setting Values according to our algorithm
      Data.setItemCurPos(original_position_val);
      Data.setItemPosition(current_positon_val);
      Data.setrotation(rotataion_val);

      
     }

Comment: Collections.sort(itemList_dump, new Comparator<MyBitamp>() {

     @Override
     public int compare(MyBitamp o1, MyBitamp o2) {
      if (o1.getItemPosition() > o2.getItemPosition()) {
       return 1;
      } else if (o1.getItemPosition() < o2.getItemPosition()) {
       return -1;
      } else {
       return 0;
      }
     }
    });

Answer (score 4):

`Collections.shuffle()` will do it for you.
`Collections.sort()` will sort it in the natural order (A,B,C,D,E..) if you want it to be sorted.